# pull out html from a href tag selenium webscraper

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pull out specific pieces of this tag:

```
<a href="/find-a-class/select-bike/1284372/?new=1" aria-label="Reserve Class with Charlotte on Thursday 21th, 5:30PM" class="open-modal reserve yellow-button" data-class-id="1284372" data-location="Studio Schedule" data-instructor="Charlotte" data-instructor-id="275" data-studio="Back Bay" data-class-type="Cycle" data-class-time="2019-11-21 17:30:00" tabindex="0">reserve</a>
```

I'm using selenium webdriver, and trying to pull out pieces of the html.

I'm finding all the links via:

```
from selenium import webdriver
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')

len(links)
>> 257

links[0]
>> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4702ae34f7d8b96da2b70080e9a0d575", element="c234a7cb-64b9-416f-8a75-dab8b4051c39")>
```

I've tried:

```
links[0]=.get_attribute('innerHTML')
>> ''
links[0]=.get_attribute('outerHTML')
>> '<a class="small-button gray-button-dark action-button-label" accesskey="k" href="#"></a>'
```

I would like to be able to pull out of the list of 257 links, just the ones where a part of the html tag is defined such as `data-instructor-id="275"`. If the 257 links all have different instructors, which of them are from instructor 275.

I've tried using `links[0].get_attribute('data-instructor-id')` to try to return the value 275, but it returns `None`

Comment: Would like to fetch  `data-instructor-id` value or what?Not clear from your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are after.If you would like to fetch the attribute value of `data-instructor-id`.Try this

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("data-instructor-id"))
```

**EDIT**:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href][@data-instructor-id]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("data-instructor-id"))
```

Comment: essentially yes thats what I'm looking for. But I've tried using `get_attribute` and it doesn't return anything. I get `Non`

Comment: Are you sure your all links have that attribute?

Comment: @MattW. : Can you try the edited answer.I have change the xpath condition.

Comment: Bam, nailed it. Thank you @KunduK